# How do I stop low disk space warnings for my recovery partition?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a brand new Omen Gaming laptop and Windows Explorer is complaining about low disk space on the recovery partition (D:) every 5 minutes.

How do I turn off these messages for **the recovery partition only**?

I've spent several hours trying to find a solution online, but have found only:

- Advice to remove extra files - however I have *not* copied any additional files to the recovery partition; it had just 5MB free right out of the box.
- Suggestions to turn off system protection and remove any system restore points - but this was already turned off for D: and the dialog reports 0 bytes used on that drive.
- Registry key hacks for Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP that turn off notifications for **all** drives, and which some report do not work on Windows 10. I'm specifically looking for a solution that works for Windows 10 Anniversary Edition or newer.

Comment: The recovery partition shouldn't even have a drive letter.

Comment: Using *Disk Management* I can see a 980MB Recovery partition that doesn't have a drive letter; there's also a ~12GB D: with label `RECOVERY`. It's the later that is causing the disk space warnings, but it does seem the actual recovery partition has no drive letter.

Comment: Technically. neither partition should have a drive letter, should remove the driver letter on the drive that is generating this error.

Comment: Could you access the D: partition to see if there are ms-backup files ?  Ms-backup shouldn't save automatically files there. The save-location might be changed.

Comment: I've verified there are no ms-backup files on D:

Comment: +1, had the same problem (HP Pavilion something). I clicked the message, and got a dialog to clear out Recycle Bin (empty) and/or user file history (4.9 GB). I deleted the file history; hope that solves the problem. If it sticks I'll write up a proper answer, but figured I'd leave you a comment so you can try it if you want.

Comment: @Shokhet Good suggestions for the main partition, but this question is about the recovery partition on my machine. The recycle bin is/was empty and I don't store my File History backups there either.

Comment: This was my recovery partition (D:), @Bevan. So far the error message hasn't come back. What does your machine show you when you click on the error message?